# Header in email using PHP is showing something different

Tags: php

```
$sentHeader = "From: Education, Annual <annualeducation@imed.org>";
```

Shows up as:

[image: Header]

But if I have:
$sentHeader = "From: annualeducation@imed.org";

shows up as `From: annualeducation.imed.org;`

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$sentHeader = 'From: "Education, Annual" <annualeducation@imed.org>';
```

Comma is a separator in headers that contain addresses, you need to put the full name in quotes if it contains a special character like this.

Comment: Just fixed it. Will test. Thanks!

Comment: I have this as the following: `$sentHeader = "From: 'Education, Annual' <annualeducation@interfaithmedical.org>";` But I am still seeing the `Education@fast.net`

Comment: Wrong type of quotes, it has to be double quotes.

Comment: @SiKni8 Simply **copy/paste** what Barmar gave you: `$sentHeader = 'From: "Education, Annual" <annualeducation@imed.org>';`

Comment: I understand and thank you for pointing it out. I just swapped the quotes. That makes a difference you think?

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. Read the RFC 2822 header specification, only double quotes are used when quoting.

Comment: WOW it DOES make a difference! weird.

Comment: @SiKni8 Indeed it does. Read up on the subject here > http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5335.txt